# Error CS0234 The type or namespace name '{0}l' does not exist in the namespace '{1}' The type or namespace name '{0}' does not exist in the namespace

Tags: c#, unity

```
using UnityEngine;
using Random = UnityEngine.Random;
using UnityEngine.Experimental.Rendering;

namespace NotSlot.HandPainted2D
{
  [RequireComponent(typeof(Light2D))]
  [AddComponentMenu("2D Hand Painted/Animate/Light Flicker")]
  public sealed class AnimateLightFlicker : MonoBehaviour
  {
    #region Inspector

    [SerializeField]
    [Range(0.1f, 10)]
    private float speed = 2;

    [SerializeField]
    [Range(0.01f, 1)]
    private float amount = 0.5f;

    #endregion


    #region Fields

    private float _base;

    private float _counter;

    public Light2D _light;

    #endregion


    #region MonoBehaviour

    private void Awake ()
    {
      _light = GetComponent<Light2D>();
    }

    public void Start ()
    {
      _base = _light.intensity;
      _counter = Random.Range(0, 10);
    }

    private void Update ()
    {
      _counter += Time.deltaTime * speed;
      _light.intensity = _base + Mathf.Sin(_counter) * amount;
    }

    #endregion
  }
}
```

The type or namespace name 'Universal' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEngine.Experimental.Rendering' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Light2D' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Me sale esto en el Unity y creo que esta en las lineas en las que dice Light2D

Comment: Tuve que poner 
Parece que tu publicación es mayormente código; por favor, añade más detalles. porque no me dejaba publicar.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Tu publicacion es solo codigo.. que hacemos con eses codigo? donde sale el error? en que linea? que tratas de hacer? que dice el error? que dice google del error?

Comment: Algún log de error que quieras compartirnos como para saber qué pasa con el código?